# Cannot cast Xiaomi Poco X3 to my Windows 10 and Windows 11

Tags: windows, screencast, poco-3

I tried casting Xiaomi Poco X3 to my Windows 10 and Windows 11 but it doesn't work. When I try to do that, I got this message.

[image]

Other smartphones can do that just fine. I tried the solution mentioned on [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/PocoPhones/comments/k5t1nc/screen_cast_does_not_seem_to_work_on_x3_nfc/) but not helping.

I wonder what I should do.

Note: I ended up using Airdroid and some alternatives. It's working fine. So I wonder why something that worked fine with Airdroid doesn't work with official companies.

Note: I tried again with another software called Miracast 4k the result is the same

[image]

Other phones work just fine